# How to get product name and image dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I am doing add to cart functionality using jQuery. On click of add to cart button product name and image should come. Statically I can do but how to get the product name and image dynamically for all divs is what I want. Please somebody help with this.

This is my HTML markup:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="prdtitem" id="anaconda">
        <div class="cartBg">
            <a href="#cart" onclick="addToCart()">
                <div class="enqry-cart pull-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="pull-left">add to enquiry cart</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <img src="images/barcunda-black.jpg" class="lazy-loaded"/>
        <h4>Barcunda Black</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="prdtitem" id="anaconda">
        <div class="cartBg">
            <a href="#cart">
                <div class="enqry-cart pull-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="pull-left">add to enquiry cart</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <img src="images/bruno-white.jpg" class="lazy-loaded"/>
        <h4>Bruno White</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="prdtitem" id="anaconda">
        <div class="cartBg">
            <a href="#cart" onclick="addToCart()">
                <div class="enqry-cart pull-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="pull-left">add to enquiry cart</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <img src="images/fantasy-brown.jpg" class="lazy-loaded"/>
        <h4>Fantasy Brown</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="prdtitem" id="anaconda">
        <div class="cartBg">
            <a href="#cart" onclick="addToCart()">
                <div class="enqry-cart pull-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="pull-left">add to enquiry cart</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <img src="images/iceberg.jpg" class="lazy-loaded"/>
        <h4>Iceberg</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="prdtitem" id="anaconda">
        <div class="cartBg">
            <a href="#cart" onclick="addToCart()">
                <div class="enqry-cart pull-left">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart pull-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="pull-left">add to enquiry cart</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <img src="images/mercury-white.jpg" class="lazy-loaded"/>
        <h4>Mercury White</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert("coming");
    var cart = [];
        $(function () {
            if (localStorage.cart) {
                cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.cart);
                // console.log(cart);
                showCart();
            }
    });
});

        function addToCart() {
            how to get product name and image here for all divs?
            // alert(price);alert(name);alert(qty);return false;
            // update qty if product is already present
            for (var i in cart) {
                if(cart[i].Product == name) {
                    cart[i].Qty = qty;
                    showCart();
                    saveCart();
                    return;
                }
            }
            // create JavaScript Object
            var item = { Product: name,  Price: price, Qty: qty };
            //console.log(item);return false;
            // alert(item);return false; 
            cart.push(item);
            console.log(cart);return false;
            saveCart();
            showCart();
        }

        function deleteItem(index){
            //alert(index);return false;
            cart.splice(index,1); // delete item at index
            showCart();
            saveCart();
        }

        function saveCart() {
            if ( window.localStorage) {
                localStorage.cart = JSON.stringify(cart);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your addToCart() function on the first line:

```
var $parent = $(this).parents('.prdtitem');

var productName = $parent.find('h4').text();
var productImage = $parent.find('img').attr('src');
```

UPDATE

```
function addToCart(elem){

    var $parent = $(elem).parents('.prdtitem');

    var productName = $parent.find('h4').text();
    var productImage = $parent.find('img').attr('src');

    // then the rest of your existing code

}
```

Comment: Can you please change `onclick="addToCart()"` to `onclick="addToCart(this)"`

Comment: Can you do a console.log(this) on the first line of your addToCart function? Tell me what you get in the console.

Comment: If I do console.log(this) also it is showing nothing chris.

Comment: Are you looking in your developer console? It would have to say something :)

Comment: I have done like below, '
   var productName = $('.prdtitem').find('h4').text();
    // console.log(productName);
   var productImage = $('.prdtitem').find('img').attr('src');
    // console.log(productImage);return false;'  But it taking all the product names

Comment: Sorry, try the updated code. I forgot to add a parameter.

Comment: I need one help how to get image thumbnail in jqurey and push into array?

Comment: Which array do you want it pushed into?

Answer (score 0):

Create a click event:

```
$('.cartBg a').click(function(){
   var img = $(this).closet('.cartBg').find('img').attr('src');
   var title = $(this).closet('.cartBg').find('h4').text();
   addToCart();
   alert(title);
});
```

Comment: Its alerting nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I see a very little jQuery involved in your addToCart function. You could simply refer it's parent container to get the source attribute of the image and the product title text:

First of all, change the way button is clicked, instead of using inline function, you could add a class reference on it, and fire the addToCart button as callback:

```html
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn-add">...</a>
```

```js
$('.btn-add').on('click', addToCart);

function addToCart() {
  var container = $(this).parents('.prdtitem');
  var thumbnailImage = container.find('img.lazy-loaded').attr('src');
  var productTitle = container.find('h4').text();
  // ... rest of your code
}
```

Now you got the image source within the `thumbnailImage` variable and the title in the `productTitle`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your function like this -

JAVASCRIPT

```
function addToCart(obj){
    var product_name = $(obj).closest('.prdtitem').find('h4').text();
    var image_src = $(obj).closest('.prdtitem').find('img.lazy-loaded').attr('src');
    alert(product_name,image_src);
}
```

In element you use this function call like this `onclick=addToCart(this)`.